# angularjs directives - how to add interpolated attribute

Tags: angularjs-directive

From what I can tell, an interpolated value string expands/resolves correctly if it's specified in the template, but not if it's added later. To demonstrate, I have the following code:

```
describe.only('directive tests - ', function() {

  it('add dynamic interpolated attribute value', function() {

    module(function($compileProvider) {
      $compileProvider.directive('hello', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          replace: true,
          template: '<a foo="{{1+1}}"></a>',
          compile: function link(tElement, tAttrs) {
            tElement.attr('bar', '{{2+2}}'); // add an interpolated attr.
          }
        };
      });
    });

    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      var element = angular.element('<div hello/>');
      $compile(element)($rootScope);
      $rootScope.$apply();
      console.log(' * ', element.prop('outerHTML'));
    });

  });

});
```

and console.log prints:

```
<a foo="2" hello="" bar="{{2+2}}" class="ng-scope"></a>'
```

and NOT:

```
<a foo="2" hello="" bar="4" class="ng-scope"></a>'
```

as I'd think. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tElement.attr('bar', $interpolate('{{2+2}}')());
```

Right, it is too late to do this in `compile`, more specifically to make changes to the directive element itself that have to be compiled (it needs to be recompiled in order to make the changes work).

But the following

```
      // replace: true,
      template: '<a foo="{{1+1}}">aa</a>',
      compile: function link(tElement, tAttrs) {
        tElement.find('a').attr('bar', '{{2+2}}');
      }
```

would work as expected.

Attribute watching and interpolation can also be done in `link` (or `controller`):

```
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('bar', function (interpolatedBar) {
          scope.bar = interpolatedBar;
        });
      }
```

It will set up a watcher on `bar` attribute (while `$interpolate(...)()` is one-time assignment and doesn't interpolate any values from scope).

Comment: did you actually try this out? I ran the changed code:
tElement.find('a').attr('bar', '{{2+2}}');
and got:
<a foo="2" hello="" class="ng-scope"></a>

Comment: The key is to remove 'replace', so 'a' becomes child element and thus is interpolated.

Comment: My apologies - I missed that. It works exactly as you suggested... On another note, I'm a bit confused about your explanation on why. I thought the compile was all about DOM manipulation.. are you saying that the outer element is already compiled and therefore cannot be modified? ie: that the container (root) element will not allow any further manipulation?

Comment: The compilation works in hierarchical manner. [This](http://triangular.io/blog/transclusion-compilation-sequence/) and [this](http://triangular.io/blog/directive-compilation-in-angularjs-step-by-step/) article nailed it quite good.

Comment: In 'compile' function you can affect how nested elements will be compiled and change their directives and data bindings. The element that hosts the directive ('<div hello>' - or '<a hello>' when 'replace' is used) was already compiled at this moment, so any changes that you would do in 'compile' won't change its data bindings. See the update on 'attrs.$observe';

Comment: Thanks for the links. They explain quite well the order of processing... I'm still not able to "see" where it says that the hosting (outer) element cannot be modified, however. Is there a unit test in the ng codebase somewhere, perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure if it was ever mentioned in the documentation explicitly. That's the knowledge I've got empirically by understanding how compile works. But you're right, specs are always great for getting idea how the things are done. Not sure if it helps you, but Angular implies that element's bound attributes can be [replaced](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.5/test/ng/compileSpec.js#L2789) or [removed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.5/test/ng/compileSpec.js#L2888), not added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89704/discussion-between-roym-and-estus).